# under what application does dev_appserver.py runs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm not able to understand how 
`google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py helloworld` runs automatically.

I mean to ask that it should run under python command as it is a python file.

is there something added to path??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `dev_appserver.py` is an executable python script. If you launch it by itself it will be executed under whichever python is the default one in your environment, see its 1st line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If you want you can also execute it with a specific python version (it has to be a python 2.7 one, though, the only one supported by GAE standard environment):

```
/specific_path/python  /path_to/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py helloworld
```